# Representation theory, addition of elements in the group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have just started looking into representation theory, and I came across the following question.

Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order 8, and $V$ be the $\mathbb{C}G-$module of dimension 2 with basis $B=\{v_1, v_2\}$ where the action of $a$ and $b$ is defined by $[a]_B=\left( \begin{matrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i 
\end{matrix}\right)$ $[b]_B=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$.

The question says, if $x=a+a^2$, find $W=\{v \in V:xv=0\}$ and decide if this is a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $V$. What I don't understand is what we mean by $a+a^2$. There is no addition defined in the group $D_8$. Does it simply mean that $xv=(a+a^2)v=av+a^2 v$ seeing as we do have addition definied on the vector space $V$?

Answer (score 4):

While $a+a^2$ doesn't make sense in $G$, it is a well defined element of $\mathbb{C}G$ (as this is the complex vector space spanned by all the elements of the group).

Comment: Ok, so am I right in saying that $xv=(a+a^2)v=av+a^2v$ for each $v$?

Comment: @Chris Yes, you are looking at a $\mathbb{C}G$-action.